# why I am not able to makemigrations to postgres DB?

Tags: django, postgresql

My current Django project is bound to default SQLite DB. Now going forward I wanted to migrate to Postgres. I have followed this [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04)

There's nothing wrong with the installation of the Postgres. I have followed exactly the same steps mentioned in the website:

1. Login with the "postgres" user.

   ```
   sudo -u postgres psql
   ```
2. Create a Database.

   ```
    CREATE DATABASE myproject;
   ```
3. Create user and assign password.

   ```
   CREATE USER myprojectuser WITH PASSWORD 'password';
   ```
4. Grant privileges to the user.

   ```
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myproject TO myprojectuser;
   ```

After this I added the below properties to my Django's settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'DB_name',
        'USER': 'new_User_name',
        'PASSWORD': 'new_user_password',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Now, when I do `python manage.py makemigrations` I get `invalid password error`.

Going forward, when I execute some postgres commands to check the environment. I have below observation.

In the Postgres shell, I execute '\l' to see the databases. I see below.

```
          Name           |  Owner   | Encoding | Collate |  Ctype  |       Access privileges
-------------------------+----------+----------+---------+---------+--------------------------------
 DB_Name                 | postgres | UTF8     | C.UTF-8 | C.UTF-8 | =Tc/postgres                  +
                         |          |          |         |         | postgres=CTc/postgres         +
                         |          |          |         |         | new_User_name=CTc/postgres
```

Then I execute '\du' to see the users status. I see below.

```
postgres=# \du
                                       List of roles
     Role name     |                         Attributes                         | Member of
-------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+-----------
 postgres          | Superuser, Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
 new_User_name     |                                                            | {}
```

So, from the above output, I assume that the target database is still owned by default 'postgres' user, and for the new user, I do not see any roles attributes. Since, the target Database is still owned by default 'postgres' user. Therefore, even if I mention the DB name, new user and its password in the Django's settings.py file. It would not work. This is my understanding.

So, please suggest how to proceed in this case.

Comment: You have created the user name using double quotes, `new_User_name` is a different name than `"new_User_name"`. Does Python/Django pass the user name "as is" or does it convert it to lower case? Does it work if you create the user without double quotes?

Comment: I dont think that we can give anything in settings.py without quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Are you try this ??

```
   DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
            'NAME': 'myproject',
            'USER': 'myprojectuser',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '5432',
        }
    }
```

Comment: they are correctly mentioned inside the single quotes

Answer (score 0):

I was able to migrate my sqlite to postgres. But as a workaround I have used default user. and rest its set its password. I couldn't connect to the DB thru other DB user. Thank you